# Graceful termination of NSApplication with Core Data and Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an Cocoa Application (Mac OS X SDK 10.7) that is performing some processes via Grand Central Dispatch (GCD).  These processes are manipulating some Core Data NSManagedObjects (non-document-based) in a manner that I believe is thread safe (creating a new managedObjectContext for use in this thread).

**The problem** I have is when the user tries to quit the application while the dispatch queue is still running.

The NSApplication delegate is being called before actually quitting.

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
```

I get an error "Could not merge changes."  Which is somewhat expected since there are still operations being performed through the different managedObjectContext.  I am then presented with the NSAlert from the template that is generated with a core data application.

In the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html) there is a section called "Be Aware of Thread Behaviors at Quit Time" which alludes to using [replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428594-replytoapplicationshouldterminat) method.  I'm having a little trouble implementing this.

**What I would like** is for my application to complete processing the queued items and then terminate without presenting an error message to the user.  It would also be helpful to update the view or use a sheet to let the user know that the app is performing some action and will terminate when the action is complete.

Where and how would I implement this behavior?

**Solution**:
So I had a few different issues here.

1. I had blocks that were accessing core data in a `dispatch_queue` preventing my application from terminating gracefully.
2. When I tried to add a new item to the dispatch_queue a new instance of the dispatch_queue was started on a new thread.

What I did to solve this was use `NSNotificationCenter` in my `AppDelegate` (where `(NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender` was being called.  In the template code that Core Data generates add the following:

```
// Customize this code block to include application-specific recovery steps.
if (error) {
    // Do something here to add queue item in AppController
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TerminateApplicationFromQueue" object:self];
    return NSTerminateLater;
}
```

Then in `AppController` add an observer for the notification (I added this to `awakeFromNib`):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(terminateApplicationFromQueue:) name:@"TerminateApplicationFromQueue" object:nil];

    // Set initial state of struct that dispatch_queue checks to see if it should terminate the application.
    appTerminating.isAppTerminating = NO;
    appTerminating.isTerminatingNow = NO;
}
```

I have also created a `struct` that can be checked against to see if the user wants to terminate the application.  (I set the initial state of the struct in `awakeFromNib` above).  Place the `struct` after your `@synthesize` statements:

```
struct {
    bool isAppTerminating;
    bool isTerminatingNow;
} appTerminating;
```

Now for the long-running `dispatch_queue` that is preventing the app from gracefully terminating.  When I initially create this `dispatch_queue`, a for loop is used to add the items that need updating.  After this for loop is executed, I have tacked on another queue item that will check the `struct` to see if the app should terminate:

```
// Additional queue item block to check if app should terminate and then update struct to terminate if required.
dispatch_group_async(refreshGroup, trackingQueue, ^{ 
    NSLog(@"check if app should terminate");
    if (appTerminating.isAppTerminating) {
        NSLog(@"app is terminating");
        appTerminating.isTerminatingNow = YES;
    }
});
dispatch_release(refreshGroup);
```

And the method to be called when the notification is received:

```
- (void)terminateApplicationFromQueue:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Struct to check against at end of dispatch_queue to see if it should shutdown.
    if (!appTerminating.isAppTerminating) {
        appTerminating.isAppTerminating = YES;
        dispatch_queue_t terminateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.appname.terminate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);  // or NULL
        dispatch_group_t terminateGroup = dispatch_group_create();

        dispatch_group_async(terminateGroup, terminateQueue, ^{ 
            NSLog(@"termination queued until after operation is complete");
            while (!appTerminating.isTerminatingNow) {
            //  add a little delay before checking termination status again
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
            }
            NSLog(@"terminate now");
            [NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];
        });
        dispatch_release(terminateGroup);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: are you returning `NSTerminateLater` from `applicationShouldTerminate:`, as mentioned in the `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:` docs?

Comment: No I am not.  I was not sure where to add this.

Comment: What _are_ you returning, then?

Comment: Right now it is just the default boilerplate that core data generates.

So it pops up an Alert which says "Could not save changes while quiting. Quit anyway?"

If the user selects "Quit anyway" NSTerminateNow is returned, else NSTerminateCancel.

Comment: If you can't terminate promptly, you should set whatever internal state you need to signal to the other parts of your app that they need to shut down and return `NSTerminateLater`. In the template code, you could do this as the only thing in `-applicationShouldTerminate:` or do it just after the `if (!__managedObjectContext) ...` part.  Then, when your shutdown processes have completed, you call `-replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:` on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't dealt with this myself, but just from my reading of the docs, it looks like what you should do is:

1. Return `NSTerminateLater` from `applicationShouldTerminate:`. This lets the system know that your app isn't ready to terminate *just yet*, but will do so shortly.
2. Enqueue a "final" block on your dispatch queue. (You need to make sure that other blocks are not enqueued after this. This block will then be run after all the other work has been performed. Note the queue must be serial -- not one of the concurrent queues) for this to work correctly.) The "final" block should do `[NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];`, which will complete the normal termination process.

There isn't any direct way to find out whether a GCD queue is still working. The only other thing that you can do (that I know of) to handle this is to put all of the blocks into a [dispatch group](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH102-SW3), and then wait on the group in `applicationShouldTerminate:` (using [`dispatch_group_wait()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW27).

Comment: Seems like its about halfway there.  For some reason the dispatch_queue is running concurrently rather than serially.

I've tried creating my queue as

`trackingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.addtracking", NULL);`

and

`trackingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.addtracking", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);`

I am also creating a dispatch_group:

`refreshGroup = dispatch_group_create();`
Items are being added to the dispatch group:

`dispatch_group_async(refreshGroup, trackingQueue, ^{ 
        NSLog(@"some action goes here");
    });`

Comment: Waiting on the group should work whether the queue is serial or concurrent (serial is the default, too). What makes you think it's concurrent? Are you certain nothing else is being enqueued once you hit `applicationShouldTerminate:`?

Comment: I have some debugging things logging to the console in each block to let to see what's going on.  When I add the terminate block to the queue, that block is executing before other items in the queue have executed.  The app now seems to be terminating without error, but I don't want to submit an update before I am certain that things are working as expected.  As for items being added to the queue after I have submitted the `applicationShouldTerminate`, I have not created a mechanism to prevent that from happening.  I guess I could create a struct to handle that.

Comment: I just thought of one possible reason for the app to terminate right away.  My `dispatch_queue` is created in my `AppController`, while the `applicationShouldTerminate` method is in `AppDelegate`.  When I am adding the terminate block to my queue, I created a class method on `AppController` and called this from within my `AppDelegate`.  Are queues treated as regular Objective-C objects?  Meaning that, though I though I was adding an item to the same queue, I was actually adding the terminate block to a new instance of the queue?

Comment: If you're calling `dispatch_queue_create()` in two places, then, yup, you've got two different queues. The descriptive string (first argument) unfortunately doesn't have any real meaning to the system -- i.e., it sort of seems like the meaning would be "if this name has already been used for a queue, then give me that, otherwise create a new one". I'd say the best thing to do would be for the delegate to just send a message to the controller that owns the queue -- `[appController finalizeThatQueue];` -- although yes, you could pass the queue itself around just like any object.

Comment: Currently, `dispatch_queue_create()` is only called within `AppController`.  In my `AppDelegate` I am calling a class method `[AppController terminateApplicationFromQueue];` from `applicationShouldTerminate`.  This results in a new queue being created.  I could try `NSNotificationCenter` and let that handle the response within `AppController`.

Comment: It won't work with `terminateApplicationFromQueue` being a class method -- class methods don't have access to instance variables, so (unless the queue is in a global variable for some reason) there's no way that you're getting the same queue there. The app delegate is going to need a reference to the controller instance, and you're going to have to make the `terminateApplicationFromQueue` method an _instance_ method. It would probably help if you put the relevant code you're working on into the body of the question, or maybe a new question.